# Cannot login to goodreads.com using Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I am using the latest version of the Tor Browser Bundle. I have created an account for [Goodreades](http://www.goodreads.com/). After the account creation I was automatically logged in and was able to use the site. Today I tried to login again, but the screen just refreshes and nothing happens. At first I thought I had forgotten my password, but even after a password reset I was not able to login. I suppose this is a more general issue, then related to Goodreads. What settings should I change in order to be able to login?

Comment: May be they have blocked the exit relay. Try a different relay by either restarting tor or changing the identity in vidalia.

Comment: Make sure you allow javascript

Comment: The question saw no activity since February and it is unlikely that this will change. Thatswhy I close the question.